# Reusable component in SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, reusability

I'm coming to SpringMVC from the world of PHP, precisely I was working with Symfony for several years.

For your information, in Symfony, there are plugins and bundles that are created by other developers so that you could use them in your project. When I come to Spring, I don't find these notions or may be I've missed something !?.

For example, I'm looking for a component that does the registration and login form, which I think that must be done many times already, and I don't want to reinvent the wheels certainly.

So, my question is, I wonder if in Spring, are there possibilities to have and how to use reusable components?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is directly supported by the Java EE spec. You don't even need any particular framework for that. Every web container supports it out of the box. If you want some additional functionalities (like remember-me, etc.), loot at [spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

Comment: Thank you,  
The registration form is just my example of how to use third party libraries, but now I found that using third party library requires just a simple include of the JARs files, so it's ok for now!